# Is it possible to set start and end position in BackgroundAudioPlayer

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am looking around to set Start and End Position for `BackgroundAudioPlayer`. Though I can set Start Position, However I am looking to set the end position as well.

Assume, my audio file is 22 minutes and the user would like to hear only from minute 10 to minute 18. Is there any possibilities to set start and end position in `BackgroundAudioPlayer` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this challenge for a desktop application and I solved it by **starting a timer with the tick time set to the position stop-start**. When the timer fires you stop the audio player and also the timer.

You can do this with a thread also but timer seems to be a cleaner solution. Below find an example - though I use a MediaElement that belongs to the GUI (that's why I use pinvoke).

```
void sndPlayer_MediaOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Set the current position in the recording
    sndPlayer.Position = currentRecording.tPosition;

    // Start playing
    sndPlayer.Play();

    // Schedule a function to stop the player
    timerControlPlayer.Interval = (double)currentDuration * 1000.0;
    timerControlPlayer.Start();
}

void timerControlPlayer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // We don't need the timer to pop in again
    timerControlPlayer.Stop();

    // Access the gui thread (the sound player belongs to that one)
    guiDispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            sndPlayer.Stop();
            SoundPlayed(this, new SoundPlayedEventArgs(currentRecording.nSpeakerCount));
            sndPlayer.Close();
        });
}

// Used as an elegant solution to start / stop the sound player
timerControlPlayer = new System.Timers.Timer();
timerControlPlayer.Elapsed += timerControlPlayer_Elapsed;
```

Comment: Instead of a Timer, wouldn't `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(duration));` work?

Comment: Hmmm ... probably it would. Actually it might be a better solution :) So let's  let the OP decide. In my case I had a desktop application and "await" was not a solution.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of using Timer, but let me use @patrick solution if it helps.

Comment: Well it has no reason not to work. Make sure that your GUI thread is not blocked by the await clause.

Comment: Thanks, I have used the Timer, It works with slight difference. I'm checking @Patrick solution. await would be the problem for me :(